# General formula for counting ordered sequences with duplicates

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have a list of distinct allowed elements $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$. Each element $x_j$ can be repeated $i_j$ times.

How many ordered sequences of length $m<\sum_{j=1}^n i_j$ are possible?

For example, suppose the alphabet is ${A,B,C}$; A has 3 copies, B has 1, and C has 3. Then, choosing from $${A,A,A,B,C,C,C},$$ how many ordered sequences of length $m =3$ are possible?

(Hence, e.g., $A,A,B$ is distinct from $A,B,A$)

If $m=\sum_{j=1}^n i_j$, this is straightforward: $$|\text{sequences}| = \frac{(\sum_{j=1}^n i_j)!}{\prod_{j=1}^n i_j!}$$

But what if $m<\sum_{j=1}^n i_j$?

Comment: @RossMillikan I must be misunderstanding something.  If $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_j = m,$$ then it seems that you do have to use all of the characters.  However, if $~n = m,~$ then why do you have to use *all of the characters*?

Comment: @user2661923  This problem concerns sequences, so the order in which the elements are selected matters, not just how many times each element appears in the selection.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Good point, so I deleted my first comment.  However, I am still confused.  If (for example) $~m = n = 3,~$ and there are 4 A's, 1 B, and 2 C's available, and you are going to form a 3 character sequence (rather than a 7 character sequence), then you will not be using *all of the letters*.  I suspect that I am misunderstanding something besides the fact that *order matters*.

Comment: @user2661923  In your example, there would be $3^3$ sequences if we did not have the restrictions that there is only one B and only two Cs.  Only one sequence can violate the restriction that there are only two Cs.  There are $\binom{3}{2} \cdot 2$ sequences with exactly two $B$s and one with three Bs that could violate the restriction that there is only one B.  Hence, there would be $3^3 - 1 - \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2 - 1$ sequences of length $3$ that could be formed using four As, one B, and two Cs.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, your analysis agrees with how I interpret the posting.  What confuses me is the last portion of the posting, where the OP (i.e. original poster) said:  $~\color{red}{\text{If}~ m=n ~\text{this is straightforward}}.$  It seems to me, what the OP should be saying is that : $$\text{if} ~\sum_{j=1}^n i_j = m, ~\text{then it is straightforward}.$$  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user2661923  Agreed.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Edited

Comment: To get the right font and spacing for a text like "sequences" within math formatting, use `\text{sequences}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive definition.

$$
f(m,i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }m = 0 \\
\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }i_j=0 \\
f(m-1,i_1,i_2,\dots,i_j-1,\dots,i_n) &\text{if }i_j>0
\end{cases}\right) &\text{if }m > 0
\end{cases}
$$

In words: There is only one sequence of length zero, namely the empty sequence. For a non-empty sequence, you can pick any symbol $j$ as starting point if its occurrence count is non-zero. And then you follow that with a sequence that is one symbol shorter and where the occurrence count of the symbol you picked is also reduced by one.

No, this is not beautiful. Things tend to be simpler if occurrence counts are at most one (permutation with no duplicates), or sum of occurrences matches overall length (permutation with duplicates but all elements taken) or occurrence counts are infinite (just pick $m$ symbols independently from given alphabet). But this kind of mixed case you have isn't very amenable to simplifications.

The above definition would allow for an evaluation of the formula using some dynamic programming, so you might be able to re-use some previously computed values and thus avoid a computation time proportional to the final count.